# sklearn бинарная классификация

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, scipy, sklearn

Нужно предсказать, результат будет положительным или отрицательным. Есть обучающая выборка (.csv), тестовая - в них однозначные числа с дробью в 16 знаков, по типу :

```
-5.072591732401996
-1.3329991860973795
1.603036140035297
4.961737849581618
-1.568250203916486
```

Результат решения задачи - csv файл со столбцами значений 1/0 (положительный или отрицательный результат). Количество строк в файле результата должно соответствовать тестовой выборке (около 3к строк)
В качестве метрики качества - **sklearn.metrics.f1_score**

Подскажите как это вообще делать? В какие темы смотреть?
Не понимаю как модель делать, обучать её, какой результат генерить

Comment: Самый банальный ответ на ваш вопрос, это воспользуйтесь любой поисковой системой. Информации в интернете куча, как и кода. Для обучения классификатора, в выборке вам нужен еще столбец с 1 и 0, то есть с известными вам результатами. Пробуйте написать код для начала самостоятельно, если не будет получаться и будут ошибки, задайте вопрос на сайте и вам помогут их решить.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков мой вопрос в том что я не знаю где брать модель. На scikit-learn я нашла сравнение классификаторов, и там есть decision tree - дерево решений, но это не то...
 https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html
хотя бы пример какой-то найти чтобы понимать что делать

Comment: Так у вас всё-таки есть файл или колонка с таргетом 1/0 для обучающей выборки или нет? А какая модель подойдёт - это нужно пробовать. Ваши данные могут быть какие угодно. Может там подойдёт *логистическая регрессия*, если там простая формула, а может и что-то другое, нужно смотреть, пробовать.